# Text-to-Columns in Excel to show data on rows

Tags: excel

I'm importing a Javascript array in to Excel with the hope that I can analyse the code.  The array is quite long and when pasted in to Excel it looks like:
[image: JS array]

Using the text to column option I can split the text up in the way I want it, but all the text is being displayed in column 1: [image: Split text]

Is there any way I can get the text to be displayed in rows? Or manipulate the column to be a row?

Comment: Yes there is but you've provided little in the way of expected results to offer even general advice. Post your work-to-date, working or not along with some TYPED expected results. Someone viewing your question can often learn much more from looking at your coding attempt than the narrative that accompanies it.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn column data into row data, and vice versa, in Excel.
This is done by pasting the data transposed.

[Excel 2007 help here](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2), Excel 2013 example below.

Some data I want to transpose. Select cells and copy as normal.

[image: Data Example]

Right click > Paste Transposed

[image: Transpose]

My transposed results

[image: Results]